# Testing angular websocket controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to angular, or maybe just stupid. But how do I test a controller that uses angular-websocket?
It certainly isn't this:

```
describe('controllers', function(){
    beforeEach(module('myapp.controllers'));

    it('should ....', inject(function($controller) {
        //spec body
        var mycontroller = $controller('mycontroller', { 
                                          $scope: {} ,
                                          WebSocket: WebSocket
    });
    expect(mycontroller).toBeDefined();
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're after is a unit test, then I would create a mock WebSocket (a bit like you use a mock $httpBackend to test $http communication). This mock object would have the same methods as the real WebSocket object but would allow checking that you have sent something to it, and would allow manually triggering the sending of a message or the opening of a connection:

```
var mockWebSocket = new MockWebSocket();
var mycontroller = $controller('mycontroller', { 
                                      $scope: {} ,
                                      WebSocket: mockWebSocket
});
mockWebSocket.openConnection(); // that internally calls all the registered onopen callbacks
expect(mockWebSocket.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');
mockWebSocket.sendMessage('goodbye'); // that internally calls all the registered onmessage callbacks
expect($scope.lastReceivedMessage).toBe('goodbye');
```

Too bad the module doesn't come with such a mock.

Answer (score 0):

if you were using ngSocket, then you could do the following:

```js
it('should ....', inject(function($controller, ngSocket) {
        //spec body
        var myController = $controller('mycontroller', { 
                                          $scope: {} ,
                                          ngSocket: ngSocket
                                      });
          
        expect(mycontroller).toBeDefined();  
    });
```